# How to correctly type JSON object using TypeScript Interface?

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I have this big JSON object:

```
{
   "faqs":{
      "items":[
         {
            "answer":"This website supports all kinds of Instagram video downloading, whether it be Instagram video, Instagram reels or IGTV video. ",
            "question":"Can we download reels or IGTV videos from this tool?"
         },
         {
            "answer":"Yes, it is legal to download videos from Instagram. However, you should only download videos that you have the rights to. If you download a video you do not have the right to, you could infringe on copyright laws.",
            "question":"Is it legal to download videos from Instagram?"
         },
         {
            "answer":"Our website solves the same purpose. All you need is Instagram video URL to download it.",
            "question":"How to download video from Instagram?"
         },
         {
            "answer":"Our website downloads the video with audio only. If you wish to download only audio from Instagram videos, you can check out Instagram audio downloader page.",
            "question":"How to download a video from Instagram with audio?"
         }
      ],
      "heading":"FAQs for Instagram Video Downloader"
   },
   "input":{
      "placeholder":"Paste in your individual video url here..."
   },
   "button":{
      "text":"Download video"
   },
   "headings":{
      "h1":"Instagram Video Downloader",
      "h2":"Instagram video downloader features",
      "h1Paragraph":"Download Instagram videos and save them to your device.",
      "h2Paragraph":"List of top features"
   },
   "sections":[
      {
         "title":"Instagram Video Download",
         "description":{
            "paragraphs":[
               "Our website is the best place to download Instagram videos. With our simple and easy-to-use interface, you can download videos from Instagram in just a few clicks. We offer high-quality videos optimized for all devices so that you can enjoy your videos on any device."
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "title":"About Instagram Video Downloader?",
         "description":{
            "paragraphs":[
               "If you are looking for a website that will allow you to download videos from Instagram, then you are in the right place. This website is straightforward to use, and it is entirely free. Enter the URL of You can save the video to your device within seconds."
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "title":"How to Download Instagram Videos?",
         "description":{
            " paragraphs":[
               "By visiting this page, your purpose is to download an Instagram video and save it to your device. Since Instagram doesn't offer a download option, we're here to help you.",
               "1) Simply enter the Instagram video URL of your choice, and click on the Download button.",
               "2) Our servers will start fetching the video and provide you with a preview option and a download button to start downloading the video.",
               "By hitting the download button, you can save it to your device in MP4 format."
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "iconCards":[
      {
         "icon":"FaRegMoneyBillAlt",
         "title":"Free to use",
         "description":"Our website offers a free way to download Instagram videos. No registration or sign-up is required. Enter the URL of the video you wish to download and click the 'Download' button."
      },
      {
         "icon":"BsSpeedometer2",
         "title":"Fast download speeds",
         "description":"Our Instagram video downloader website offers fast download speeds so you can quickly and easily download your favorite videos."
      },
      {
         "icon":"AiOutlineVideoCamera",
         "title":"Download in HD",
         "description":"Our Instagram video downloader allows you to download videos in high definition, so you can enjoy your favorite videos in the best quality possible."
      },
      {
         "icon":"TbInfinity",
         "title":"No Download Limits",
         "description":"Our Instagram video downloader has no download limits, so you can download as many videos as you want!"
      },
      {
         "icon":"GrSecure",
         "title":"Fully Secured",
         "description":"Our website is fully secured with the latest security features. Your data is safe with us the latest encryption technology to protect your data."
      },
      {
         "icon":"ImFileVideo",
         "title":"Mp4 format",
         "description":"Our website offers the ability to download Instagram videos in MP4 format. This popular video format is widely compatible with many devices and media players."
      }
   ]
}
```

which I was able to correctly type like this

```
    export interface PageProps {
      input: {
        placeholder: string
      }
      button: {
        text: string
      }
      iconCards: {
        icon: string
        title: string
        description: string
      }[]
      sections: {
        title: string
        description: { paragraphs: string[] }
      }[]
      faqs: {
        heading: string
        items: {
          question: string
          answer: string
        }[]
      }
      headings: {
        h1: string
        h1Paragraph: string
        h2: string
        h2Paragraph: string
      }
    }
```

Using the auto translate extension from visual studio code, I was able to translate it into multiple languages.
However, due to the process the JSON structure was altered. Instead of having an Array of objects in the JSON object, I have only objects with keys, containing a number:

```
 {
  "faqs": {
    "items": {
      "0": {
        "answer": "Diese Website unterstützt alle Arten des Herunterladens von Instagram-Videos, egal ob es sich um Instagram-Videos, Instagram-Rollen oder IGTV-Videos handelt.",
        "question": "Können wir Filmrollen oder IGTV-Videos von diesem Tool herunterladen?"
      },
      "1": {
        "answer": "Ja, es ist legal, Videos von Instagram herunterzuladen. Sie sollten jedoch nur Videos herunterladen, für die Sie die Rechte haben. Wenn Sie ein Video herunterladen, für das Sie keine Rechte haben, könnten Sie gegen Urheberrechtsgesetze verstoßen.",
        "question": "Ist es legal, Videos von Instagram herunterzuladen?"
      },
      "2": {
        "answer": "Unsere Website erfüllt den gleichen Zweck. Alles, was Sie brauchen, ist die Instagram-Video-URL, um sie herunterzuladen.",
        "question": "Wie lade ich Videos von Instagram herunter?"
      },
      "3": {
        "answer": "Unsere Website lädt das Video nur mit Audio herunter. Wenn Sie nur Audio von Instagram-Videos herunterladen möchten, können Sie die Instagram-Audio-Downloader-Seite besuchen.",
        "question": "Wie lade ich ein Video von Instagram mit Audio herunter?"
      }
    },
    "heading": "FAQs für Instagram Video Downloader"
  },
  "input": {
    "placeholder": "Fügen Sie hier Ihre individuelle Video-URL ein..."
  },
  "button": {
    "text": "Video herunterladen"
  },
  "headings": {
    "h1": "Instagram-Video-Downloader",
    "h2": "Funktionen des Instagram-Video-Downloaders",
    "h1Paragraph": "Laden Sie Instagram-Videos herunter und speichern Sie sie auf Ihrem Gerät.",
    "h2Paragraph": "Liste der Top-Features"
  },
  "sections": {
    "0": {
      "title": "Herunterladen von Instagram-Videos",
      "description": {
        "paragraphs": {
          "0": "Unsere Website ist der beste Ort, um Instagram-Videos herunterzuladen. Mit unserer einfachen und benutzerfreundlichen Oberfläche können Sie Videos von Instagram mit nur wenigen Klicks herunterladen. Wir bieten qualitativ hochwertige Videos, die für alle Geräte optimiert sind, damit Sie Ihre Videos auf jedem Gerät genießen können."
        }
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "title": "Über Instagram Video Downloader?",
      "description": {
        "paragraphs": {
          "0": "Wenn Sie nach einer Website suchen, die es Ihnen ermöglicht, Videos von Instagram herunterzuladen, dann sind Sie hier genau richtig. Diese Website ist einfach zu bedienen und völlig kostenlos. Geben Sie die URL von ein. Sie können das Video innerhalb von Sekunden auf Ihrem Gerät speichern."
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "Wie lädt man Instagram-Videos herunter?",
      "description": {
        " paragraphs": {
          "0": "Durch den Besuch dieser Seite möchten Sie ein Instagram-Video herunterladen und auf Ihrem Gerät speichern. Da Instagram keine Download-Option anbietet, sind wir hier, um Ihnen zu helfen.",
          "1": "1) Geben Sie einfach die Instagram-Video-URL Ihrer Wahl ein und klicken Sie auf die Schaltfläche Herunterladen.",
          "2": "2) Unsere Server beginnen mit dem Abrufen des Videos und bieten Ihnen eine Vorschauoption und eine Download-Schaltfläche, um mit dem Herunterladen des Videos zu beginnen.",
          "3": "Durch Klicken auf die Download-Schaltfläche können Sie es im MP4-Format auf Ihrem Gerät speichern."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "iconCards": {
    "0": {
      "icon": "FaRegGeldRechnungAlt",
      "title": "Kostenlos zu verwenden",
      "description": "Unsere Website bietet eine kostenlose Möglichkeit, Instagram-Videos herunterzuladen. Es ist keine Registrierung oder Anmeldung erforderlich. Geben Sie die URL des Videos ein, das Sie herunterladen möchten, und klicken Sie auf die Schaltfläche „Herunterladen“."
    },
    "1": {
      "icon": "BsTachometer2",
      "title": "Schnelle Download-Geschwindigkeiten",
      "description": "Unsere Instagram-Video-Downloader-Website bietet schnelle Download-Geschwindigkeiten, sodass Sie Ihre Lieblingsvideos schnell und einfach herunterladen können."
    },
    "2": {
      "icon": "AiOutlineVideoCamera",
      "title": "In HD herunterladen",
      "description": "Mit unserem Instagram-Video-Downloader können Sie Videos in High Definition herunterladen, damit Sie Ihre Lieblingsvideos in der bestmöglichen Qualität genießen können."
    },
    "3": {
      "icon": "TbInfinity",
      "title": "Keine Download-Limits",
      "description": "Unser Instagram-Video-Downloader hat keine Download-Limits, sodass Sie so viele Videos herunterladen können, wie Sie möchten!"
    },
    "4": {
      "icon": "GrSicher",
      "title": "Vollständig gesichert",
      "description": "Unsere Website ist vollständig mit den neuesten Sicherheitsfunktionen gesichert. Ihre Daten sind bei uns sicher. Die neueste Verschlüsselungstechnologie schützt Ihre Daten."
    },
    "5": {
      "icon": "ImFileVideo",
      "title": "Mp4-Format",
      "description": "Unsere Website bietet die Möglichkeit, Instagram-Videos im MP4-Format herunterzuladen. Dieses beliebte Videoformat ist weitgehend kompatibel mit vielen Geräten und Mediaplayern."
    }
  }
}
```

My question would be, what does  the TypeScript interface above need to look like?
How can I type an object containing multiple keys(numbers), that are pointing to an object , rather than just having an array of objects.

Comment: The keys, e.g. `"0"`, are strings, not numbers. `faqs.items` is a `Record<string, { question: string; answer: string }>`. I would create an interface `Item`.

Comment: You should open an issue on the extension's repository.